# Why is film stuck in my Advantix APS camera?

Tags: aps

I bought a cheap Kodak Advantix C450 which I’m quite certain is not working (I am a beginner in film photography so I'm pretty clueless)

I was sure it was working at one point but now I’m not sure. My issue is that the lever that opens the film slot won’t move.(I've been able to open it fine multiple times already.) I was thinking of getting a new camera and using the film since this camera is a bit hit and miss.

Does anyone know why the film is stuck in the camera? How can I get it out?

I also took the batteries out at one point which might have something to do with it?
[image]

Comment: Michael was doing you a favor. People won't bother to help if you can't be bothered to construct a somewhat grammatically correct question. If you're not a native English speaker, I apologize.

Comment: You say you opened the film slot multiple times before, but now can't. Is it because there is film inside now, which wasn't there before? The camera may lock the film slot once film is loaded - to stop newbies from opening the door and ruining the film. (You know film gets ruined if exposed to light, right?) Is there a button somewhere to force a film rewind? After rewinding the film, try opening the door then. You'll need batteries inside for the rewind to work.

Comment: APS film has an [indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Photo_System#Film_and_cartridge) on one end of the cartridge to show the state of the film: new / partially-exposed / fully-exposed / processed. If the above worked, and you want to re-use this film, you might be able to just stick it back in, and the camera might advance the film to the next available frame, and you can start taking photos where you left off (that is, if you haven't exposed the entire roll already). Not all cameras offer this feature though, so your camera may refuse to accept a partially-exposed roll of film

Comment: If you haven't taken any photos at all, the cartridge indicator may still show as "partially-exposed", simply because you loaded the film in the camera. But there's a way to manually manipulate that indicator, so that you can reload the canister into the camera and fool the camera into thinking it's a new roll.

Comment: Yeah the camera pretty much doesn’t work but has probably locked the film in like you said. I’m just going to keep trying to wind the film to make it think it exposed and hopefully it should let me take it out.